# Is there a standard function like Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(n), but for BigIntegers?

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm working with huge numbers (Millions of digits), and that function would be very useful, instead of doing BigInteger.shiftright(n) in a while loop.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just read the documentation for [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has [BigInteger.getLowestSetBit()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#getLowestSetBit()) which does what you want:

> Returns the index of the rightmost (lowest-order) one bit in this BigInteger (the number of zero bits to the right of the rightmost one bit).

Comment: Would you look at that beautiful function, thanks a lot! Accepting the answer in 5 minutes.